# Specific Graph and need to more Creative solution

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph, tree, complexity-theory

Directed Graph `(|V|=a, |E|=b)` is given.
each vertexes has specific weight. we want for each vertex `(1..a)` find a vertex with maximum weight that can be reachable from that vertex.

> Update 1: one nice answer is prepare by @Paul in O(b + a log a). but I
> search for O(a + b) algorithms, if any?
>
> Is there any different efficient or fastest any other ways for doing it?

Comment: The approach of directly using BFS/DFS has some issues. E.g. consider a graph `a -> b, a -> c, b->a` with weights `a = 0, b = 0, c = 3`. Now if you start at node `a` you'll reach node `b` and terminate there. Maximum assignable weight: 0. But the maximum reachable node is actually `c` with weight 3. Or did I get sth wrong about your idea?]

Comment: @Paul exactly. you are right. I was mistake. you answer is fine at least I think.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it's possible to modify Tarjan's SCC algorithm to solve this problem in linear time.

Tarjan's algorithm uses two node fields to drive its SCC finding logic: `index`, which represents the order in which the algorithm discovers the nodes; and `lowlink`, the minimum `index` reachable by a sequence of tree arcs followed by a back arc. As part of the same depth-first traversal, we can compute another field, `maxweight`, which has one of two meanings:

- For a node not yet included in a finished SCC, it represents the maximum weight reachable by a sequence of tree arcs, optionally followed by a cross arc to another SCC and then any subsequent path.
- For nodes in a finished SCC, it represents the maximum weight reachable.

The logic for computing `maxweight` is as follows. If we discover an arc from `v` to a new node `w`, then `vw` is a tree arc, so we compute `w.maxweight` recursively and update `v.maxweight = max(v.maxweight, w.maxweight)`. If `w` is on the stack, then we do nothing, because `vw` is a back arc and not included in the definition of `maxweight`. Otherwise, `vw` is a cross arc, and we do the same update that we would have done for a tree arc, just without the recursive call.

When Tarjan's algorithm identifies an SCC, it's because it has a node `r` with `r.lowlink == r.index`. Since `r` is the depth-first search root of this SCC, its value of `maxweight` is correct for the whole SCC. Instead of recording each node in the SCC, we simply update its `maxweight` to `r.maxweight`.

Comment: so would you please discuss about running time in worst case?

Comment: @user355834 Linear time (O(a + b)), like Tarjan's algorithm, since I didn't alter the control structure of Tarjan's algorithm in any way.

Comment: nice answer. so I think the time is remains as O(a+b)? isnt it?

Comment: @user3661613 yes, it's O(a + b).

Comment: would you please tell me in the other answer, we get more than linear time? am I right? and one of your positive answer side is no need to reverse graph. would u please correct me?

Answer (score 1):

Sort all nodes by weight in decreasing order and create the graph `g'` with all edges in `E` reversed (i.e. if there's an edge `a -> b` in `g`, there's an edge `b -> a` in `g'`). In this graph you can now propagate the maximum-value by simple DFS. Do this iteratively for all nodes and terminate when a maximum-weight has already been assigned.

As pseudocode:

```
dfs_assign_weight_reachable(node, weight):
    if node.max_weight_reachable >= weight:
        return

    node.max_weight_reachable = weight

    for n = neighbor of node:
        dfs_assign_weight_reachable(n, weight)

g' = g with all edges reversed
nodes = nodes from g' sorted descendingly by weight
assign max_weight_reachable = -inf to each node in nodes

for node in nodes:
    dfs_assign_weight_reachable(node, node.weight)
```

UPDATE:
The tight bound is `O(b + a log a)`. `a log a` is caused by the sorting step. And each edge gets visited once during the reversal step and once during the assigning maximum weights, giving the second term in the `max`-expression.

Acknowledgement:
I'd like to thank [@SerialLazer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10208481/serial-lazer) for the time invested in a discussion about the time-complexity of the above algorithm and helping me figure out the correct bound.

Comment: so you means O(an) is upper bound of O(a + b) , and your algorithm definitely solve problem in O(a + b), isnt it?

Comment: @user355834 pretty much. I haven't had the time yet to figure out a tight upper bound, but it should be close to `O(a log a)` (the sorting-step at the start).

Comment: it's very good if you add time complexity in more sophisticated way. some misunderstanding point at first you write takes O(a + b), at last O(a log a), sorry for my misunderstanding point.

Comment: @user355834 actually that was a mistake on my part. I had focused too much on the branching factor in an attempt to figure out the precise time-complexity and completely forgot that the first step of my algorithm was to sort nodes.

Comment: @Paul I think it wouldnt depend on the branching factor at all. Since we are already reverse-sorting based on weights; the total number of edges we will traverse will always be `= a`. So that step is always `O(a)`. Giving the complexity as : `O(aloga)`

Comment: @SerialLazer well, it does. Imagine a graph `a -> b, a-> c` and `b` having the maximum weight. We'll visit `a` a total of three times: once to set the weight of `b` as maximum reachable weight, then from `c`, but the maximum weight is already set and then again when directly calling DFS from `a`, which also directly terminates. You could also construct an example where it's more obvious that it depends on the number of outgoing edges, not the number of vertices. But I've figured out the tight bound now. It's `O(max(b, a log a))`.

Comment: @Paul Not really if you maintain a hashmap for all the nodes that have already been set with the maximum weight. The maximum number of visits u need to make to set all weights would be O(a) itself.

Comment: @SerialLazer the problem - no matter how you maintain information about visited nodes - is that you'll have to do that lookup multiple times. And each of those lookups adds to time-complexity. E.g. in the previous example-graph, you'll have to check the hashmap when performing DFS from `c` and `a`. So it's a total of three lookups either way

Comment: @Paul Which is why there's O(a). Can u produce an example where it would be O(|edges|) with the hashmap?

Comment: Think about this: Lets say reversed-Graph = `b->a->{sub-graph} c->{subgraph} b has highest-weight`. The `subgraph` would only be traversed once to assign each of the vertices with max-wt=b; post that when doing the traversal for wt=c, we wont do it again for the subgraph using a hashmap

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224907/discussion-between-paul-and-serial-lazer).

Comment: I think there is an efficient version with at most O(a + b). am I wrong?

Comment: @user355834 well, this one is the most efficient I could come up with. For special cases you might employ a [linear-time sorting algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Non-comparison_sorts), but short of that I can't think of any way to get beyond the limit of `O(b + a log a)`.

Comment: @SerialLazer reversing graph makes O(b) + getting node with maximum weights O(a) + DFS O(a+b) --> All = O(a+b + a+b)= O(a+b). Paul please verify me, too.

Comment: @user355834 the problem is, there are probably some vertices from which the vertex with maximum weight can't be reached. So you'll need to do a DFS from the one with second highest weight as well. And the one with the third highest, .... Unless your graph is strongly connected, finding the maximum weight won't suffice. Otherwise this algorithm wouldn't be needed at all and you could simply assign the maximum weight as maximum reachable weight for all vertices

Comment: would you please consider two case in your answer? when we need to run DFS again and related time complexity? a minor change will be updated in my question.

Comment: @user355834 consider the graph `a -> b, a -> c` with weights ordered as `a < b < c`. The first run of DFS won't reach vertex `b`, so we have to start a separate DFS from `b`

Comment: so if we forget about repeated DFS, can we say O(a + b). or maybe using BFS?

Comment: 1- reverse all edge O(b)  2- travers all vertex to get max O(a). 3) start from max and dfs o(a+b) up to yet all is O(a+b). we have challenge when some node cannot be reachable. so loop over all vertex O( a (a+b) ) , but tricky here, you didn't start dfs on previous visited vertex so again O(a+b) where is wrong?  @SerialLazer

Comment: @user355834 the choice between DFS and BFS doesn't make much of a difference performance-wise, apart from BFS probably being a bit slower in practice. Your last approach is `O(a(a + b)) = O(a^2 + a*b)`, which is even worse. Consider the graph `a -> b, a -> c, a -> d, a -> ...`. You'll still visit every single vertex except for `a`, but take linear time on each iteration to figure out which vertex to visit next. You didn't gain anything unless your graph is at least almost strongly connected.