# find the most valuable vertex among all reachable vertices

Tags: java, python, algorithm, math, data-structures

I have a Directed Graph `G=(V,E)` that each vertex `v` has two properties:

- `r` indicating the worthiness
- `m` indicating the highest `v'`'s `r` (where `v'` is a reachable vertex from `v`).

I need to find `m`s for all vertices in `O(|V|+|E|)` time.

For example,

Initial `G`

```
A(r = 1, m = 1) → B(r = 3, m = 3) ← C(r = 2, m = 2)
↓
D(r = 4, m = 4)
```

has to be

```
A(r = 1, m = 4) → B(r = 3, m = 3) ← C(r = 2, m = 3)
↓
D(r = 4, m = 4)
```

I searched SO and found some [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64945501/specific-graph-and-need-to-more-creative-solution), but one of the answers does not bound in time and another answer is very badly explained. Is there any simpler idea here?

Comment: Wait, do you mean reachable with steps in between or directly reachable (adjacent)?

Comment: @orlp it means you can go from a to b and b can be reachable by a. is it clear?

Comment: @orlp please see other post algorithm. I mentioned link in the question

Comment: What my question is, suppose we have `a -> b -> c`. Is `c` considered reachable from `a` in this scenario?

Comment: sure @orlp your example correct,

Comment: what do you calculate these value for original graph in first step? at first all of them is zero !? @GyuHyeonChoi

Comment: Are all `m`s 0 initially? Isn't it self reachable? Then should `B.m` be `0 → 3` or `0 → 0`?

Comment: no you are correct @GyuHyeonChoi

Comment: would you please check the related post in question? @GyuHyeonChoi

Comment: I think it may take some time to understand their answers... So is `O(|V| + |E|)` is enough for you, right?

Comment: @GyuHyeonChoi sure. this is very hard question.

Comment: Do you have to start from one staring vertex? Or, do you have multiple starting vertices?

Comment: nothing is important just time complexity and finding for all vertex the request value. @GyuHyeonChoi

Comment: @fiona2019 Can I assume there are no subgraphs not connected? Additionally, how can you reach vertices with only incoming edges? Is a vertex aware of incoming edges and can it be traversed through reverse direction?

Comment: @fiona2019 are you still looking for an answer?

Answer (score 3):

In practice, I would use use the algorithm from Ehsan's answer, but it's not quite O(V+E).  If you really need that complexity, then you can do this:

1. Divide the graph into strongly-connected components using, e.g., [Tarjan's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarjan%27s_strongly_connected_components_algorithm) This is  O(V+E).
2. Make a graph of the SCCs.  Every node in an SCC is reachable from every other one, so the node for each SCC in the new graph gets the highest `r` value in the SCC. You can do this in O(V+E) too.
3. The graph of SCCs is acyclic, so you can do a [topological sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting).  All the popular algorithms for that are O(V+E).
4. Process the SCC nodes in reverse topological order, calculating each `m` from neighbors.  Because all the edges point from later to earlier nodes, the inputs for each node will be finished by the time you get to it.  This is O(V+E) too.
5. Go through the original graph, setting every node's `m` to the value for its component in the SCC graph.  O(V)

Comment: it works on O(V+E) really ! what you tell that not quite O(V+E) ! i think you say about that algorithm am I right?

Comment: You mean what you said about Ehsan's answer?  Yes, you were right.  He has corrected the complexity statement.

Comment: but your nice algorithm works in O(V+E) am I right? is it possible makes a little example or it's too long? this is very nice question I think. and also very nice answer. if there is simple short graph that show output of each step is very nice.

Comment: would you please clear "Because all the edges point from later to earlier nodes, the inputs for each node will be finished by the time you get to it. " some misunderstanding for this sentence.

Comment: A topological sort orders the vertices so that every edge in the graph points from a vertex that is earlier in the order to a vertex that is later.  If you visit vertices in *reverse* toplogical order, then all edges from the current vertex will point to vertices that you've *already* visited.  Since you've already visited them, they will have the correct `m` value, so you just need to pick the maximum one and compare to the current vertex `r` in order to calculate `m` for the current vertex.

Comment: And yes, this algorithm works in O(V+E).  The extra work that you're asking for, though -- an example graph with outputs from each step, etc -- is more than I want to do.  The implementation of this algorithm is a little complicated, which is why I would use Ehsan's in practice.

Comment: @MattTimmermans Tarjan's algorithm already outputs SCCs in topological order, so you can skip that step. You don't need to explicitly construct the SCC graph either; it's enough to check all of the arcs leaving the current SCC and then assign the max value to each of the nodes in the current SCC. Fold this step into the main DFS and you get the answer that I posted on the linked question.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat I see your previous answer but really that answer is very expert. would you please post it your answer in a simpler manner.

Comment: Thanks for your description. I think David is right and some step can be merged. would you please correct it.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat Yes, you're right.  I didn't see the linked answer, but it's essentially the same.  I was aiming for a clear explanation more than a sketch of the implementation.

Comment: @MattTimmermans thanks so much, would you please add one or two line that if we use logic based on Tarjans, how many step will changed? Thanks for nice and clear algorithm.

Comment: would you please add a bit detail to solve my doubt and finalize and accept

Comment: sure. there are lots of people here try to learn to others. no worry. at least one person clearly learn me in future. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Use following `O(E+V*log(V))` algorithm :

```
- Reverse all directions
- while |V| > 0 do
    find max(v) from remaining nodes in V
    from that node execute DFS and find all reachable nodes and update their m as max(V)
    remove all updated nodes from V
```

the time-complexity of this algorithm is as your request `O(V*log(V)+E)`

Comment: How you find Max (V)? time complexity for max?

Comment: O(n) which n is remaining nodes in V. at the end you will parse each node just once then it's O(|V|)

Comment: Suppose array is reverse sorted. at first iteration you parse O(n) then O(n-1) then O(n-2) ... to get max ! am I wrong?

Comment: Actually in each step AT LEAST one nodes will be removed from V. if the subtree expanded from DFS just includes 1 node. then yes in worst case you have O(n)+O(n-1)+... which is equal to O(n^2) . Also you can sort the elements by O(n*log(n)) at the beginning to avoid worst case

Comment: if you sort then your time is not O(V+E) this is exactly the problem here

Comment: O( E + V log V ).  Nice algorithm, though.   Making an initial sorted list and crossing off removed vertices is probably the best way to implement the find-max.  The cross-off marks can double as your visited set, so the resulting implementation is super simple.

Answer (score 1):

**How to solve the problem?**

1. Reachable vertices in a directed graph

- Which vertices can a given vertex visit?
- Which vertices can visit the given vertex?

We are dealing with directed graphs. So, we need to find [strongly connected components](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strongly_connected_component) to answer the questions like above efficiently for this problem.

[image]

2. Once we know the strongly connected components, we can deal with the highest worthiness part.

In every strongly connected component, what is the highest worthiness value? Update accordingly.

Both steps are possible with O(V + E). With proper thought process, I believe it should be able to do both the steps in a single pass.

**How to find strongly connected components?**

1. [Kosaraju's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kosaraju%27s_algorithm)
2. [Tarjan's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarjan%27s_strongly_connected_components_algorithm)
3. [Path-based strong component algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path-based_strong_component_algorithm)

- If you are looking for something simple, go for Kosaraju's algorithm. To me, it is the simplest of the above three.
- If you are looking for efficiency, Kosaraju's algorithm takes two depth-first traversals but the other two algorithms accomplish the same within 1 depth-first traversal.
- [A Space-Efficient Algorithm for Finding Strongly Connected Components](https://homepages.ecs.vuw.ac.nz/%7Edjp/files/IPL15-preprint.pdf) mentions that Tarjan’s algorithm required at most v(2 + 5w) bits of storage,  where w is the machine’s word size. The improvement mentioned in the paper reduces the space requirements to v(1 + 3w) bits in the worst case.

**Implementation:**

Apparently, you are looking for some type of implementation.

- For the mentioned 3 ways of finding strongly connected components, you can [find java implementation here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/127599/comparing-linear-time-strongly-connected-component-algorithms-in-java).
- There are multiple Path-based strong component algorithms. To my knowledge, Gabow's algorithm is much simpler to understand than Tarjan's algorithm and the latest in path-based strong component algorithms. You can [find java implementation for Gabow's algorithm here](https://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/42digraph/GabowSCC.java.html).

Comment: very nice, very simple. this is exactly understandable. one part is need a little more detail. when I find SCC what should we do next?

Comment: @fiona2019 Say the adjacency graph is A: {B}, B: {A}, C: {B, D}, D: {C}. Let us say worthiness for A, B, C, D is 1, 2, 3, 4 respectively. In the given graph, there are two strongly connected components (A, B) and (C, D). Max worthiness in the first SCCs is 2. So update max worthiness of A, B to 2. Similarly, update worthiness of C, D to 4. Done. Simple.

Comment: if you can describe me the algorithm in very easy accept this is cover my answer and accept it. 1) we convert graph to SCC. so using reverse topological on SCC graph? then?

Comment: @fiona2019: We don't convert the graph to SCC. We just figure out the what the SCCs are. In the image shown in my answer, the areas shown with dotted border are SCCs. e.g. a, b, e is one SCC. Run a simple for loop and understand what is maximum worthiness for a, b, e. Let us say the worthiness of a, b, e is 10, 20, 30 respectively. So, vertex e has maximum worthiness i.e. 30. So, update worthiness of vertices of a and b to 30. Do the same for other two SCCs in the graph shown as image in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I am adding this answer, although there are correct answers with upvotes before me, only because you tagged [java](/questions/tagged/java) and [python](/questions/tagged/python). So I will add java implementation now, and if needed the python implementation will follow.

### The algorithm

This is a tweak on the classic topological sort:

1. foreach vertex:

   1. foreach neighbour:

      1. if didn't yet calculate `m`, calculate.
   2. Take the maximum of yourself and neighbours. Mark yourself as visited, and if asked again for `m`, return the calculated.

It is implemented at `calculateMostValuableVertex`.

### Time computation complexity

1. foreach vertex (O(|V|))
   2. foreach edge(O(|E|) totally, as it will eventually go over each edge once.):

   3. If not yet computed, compute `m`.

Please note that foreach vertex, it will be calculated either in stage 1, or 3. not twice, wince it is checked before the calculation.
Therefore the time complexity of this algorithm is O(|V| + |E|)

### Assumptions

This solution relies heavily on the fact that `HashMap` in Java does operations such as add/update in `O(1)`. That is true in average, but if that is not enough, the same idea can be fully implemented only with arrays, which will improve the solution into `O(|V|+|E|)` in the worst case.

### Implementation

Let's first define the basic classes:

1. Vertex:

   ```java
   import java.util.ArrayList;

   class Vertex {
       String label;
       public int r; // Worthiness
       public int m; // Highest worthiness.

       Vertex(String label, int r, int m) {
           this.label = label;
           this.r = r;
           this.m = m;
       }

       @Override
       public int hashCode() {
           final int prime = 31;
           int result = 1;
           result = prime * result * r * m
                   + ((label == null) ? 0 : label.hashCode());
           return result;
       }

       @Override
       public boolean equals(final Object obj) {
           if (this == obj)
               return true;
           if (obj == null)
               return false;
           if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
               return false;
           final Vertex other = (Vertex) obj;

           boolean labelEquals;
           if (label == null) {
               labelEquals = other.label == null;
           } else {
               labelEquals = label.equals(other.label);
           }
           return labelEquals && r == other.r && m == other.m;
       }

       @Override
       public String toString() {
           return "Vertex{" +
                   "label='" + label + '\'' +
                   ", r=" + r +
                   ", m=" + m +
                   '}';
       }
   }
   ```

   It is important to define the methods `equals` and `hashCode` so later on their hash computations will work as expected.
2. Graph:

   ```java
   class Graph {

       private final Map<Vertex, List<Vertex>> adjVertices = new HashMap<>();
       private final Map<String, Vertex> nameToVertex = new HashMap<>();
       private final List<Vertex> vertices = new ArrayList<>();

       void addVertex(String label, int r, int m) {
           Vertex vertex = new Vertex(label, r, m);
           adjVertices.putIfAbsent(vertex, new ArrayList<>());
           nameToVertex.putIfAbsent(label, vertex);
           vertices.add(vertex);
       }

       void addEdge(String label1, String label2) {
           adjVertices.get(nameToVertex.get(label1)).add(nameToVertex.get(label2));
       }

       public void calculateMostValuableVertex() {
           Map<Vertex, Boolean> visitedVertices = new HashMap<>();
           for (Vertex vertex : vertices) {
               visitedVertices.put(vertex, false);
           }

           for (Vertex vertex : vertices) {
               if (visitedVertices.get(vertex)) {
                   continue;
               }

               calculateMostValuableVertexInternal(vertex, visitedVertices);
           }
       }

       public void calculateMostValuableVertexInternal(Vertex vertex, Map<Vertex, Boolean> visitedVertices) {
           List<Vertex> neighbours = adjVertices.get(vertex);
           visitedVertices.put(vertex, true);
           int max = vertex.r;

           for (Vertex neighbour: neighbours) {
               if (visitedVertices.get(neighbour)) {
                   max = Math.max(max, neighbour.m);
               } else {
                   calculateMostValuableVertexInternal(neighbour, visitedVertices);
                   max = Math.max(max, neighbour.m);
               }
           }

           vertex.m = max;
       }

       @Override
       public String toString() {
           StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
           Iterator<Map.Entry<Vertex, List<Vertex>>> iter = adjVertices.entrySet().iterator();
           while (iter.hasNext()) {
               Map.Entry<Vertex, List<Vertex>> entry = iter.next();
               sb.append(entry.getKey());
               sb.append('=').append('"');
               sb.append(entry.getValue());
               sb.append('"');
               if (iter.hasNext()) {
                   sb.append(',').append('\n');
               }
           }

           return "Graph{" +
                   "adjVertices=\n" + sb +
                   '}';
       }
   }
   ```

Finally, to run the above logic, you can do:

```java
Graph g = new Graph();

g.addVertex("A", 1, 1);
g.addVertex("B", 3, 3);
g.addVertex("C", 2, 2);
g.addVertex("D", 4, 4);

g.addEdge("A", "B");
g.addEdge("C", "B");
g.addEdge("A", "D");

g.calculateMostValuableVertex();

System.out.println(g);
```

The output of the above is:

```
Graph{adjVertices=
Vertex{label='A', r=1, m=4}="[Vertex{label='B', r=3, m=3}, Vertex{label='D', r=4, m=4}]",
Vertex{label='D', r=4, m=4}="[]",
Vertex{label='B', r=3, m=3}="[]",
Vertex{label='C', r=2, m=3}="[Vertex{label='B', r=3, m=3}]"}
```

as expected. It supports graphs with cycles as well. For example the output of:

```
Graph g = new Graph();

g.addVertex("A", 1, 1);
g.addVertex("B", 3, 3);
g.addVertex("C", 2, 2);
g.addVertex("D", 4, 4);
g.addVertex("E", 5, 5);
g.addVertex("F", 6, 6);
g.addVertex("G", 7, 7);

g.addEdge("A", "B");
g.addEdge("C", "B");
g.addEdge("A", "D");
g.addEdge("A", "E");
g.addEdge("E", "F");
g.addEdge("F", "G");
g.addEdge("G", "A");

g.calculateMostValuableVertex();

System.out.println(g);
```

is:

```
Graph{adjVertices=
Vertex{label='A', r=1, m=7}="[Vertex{label='B', r=3, m=3}, Vertex{label='D', r=4, m=4}, Vertex{label='E', r=5, m=7}]",
Vertex{label='B', r=3, m=3}="[]",
Vertex{label='C', r=2, m=3}="[Vertex{label='B', r=3, m=3}]",
Vertex{label='D', r=4, m=4}="[]",
Vertex{label='E', r=5, m=7}="[Vertex{label='F', r=6, m=7}]",
Vertex{label='F', r=6, m=7}="[Vertex{label='G', r=7, m=7}]",
Vertex{label='G', r=7, m=7}="[Vertex{label='A', r=1, m=7}]"}
```

Comment: Does this work when the graph has cycles?

Comment: @DavidEisenstat Actually I had a bug there, but I fixed it and added example

Comment: @DavidEisenstat would you please add a simple algorithm as an answer too? I read most of your answer is very simple but linked answer in my question is very complex

Comment: @DavidEisenstat because none of these answer good enough to set bounty.

Comment: @fiona2019 did you try my solution? It didn't work for you? What didn't work?

Answer (score 0):

I implemented my answer from the linked question in Python. The lines that don't reference `minreach` closely follow Wikipedia's description of Tarjan's SCC algorithm.

```
import random


def random_graph(n):
    return {
        i: {random.randrange(n) for j in range(random.randrange(n))} for i in range(n)
    }


class SCC:
    def __init__(self, graph):
        self.graph = graph
        self.index = {}
        self.lowlink = {}
        self.stack = []
        self.stackset = set()
        self.minreach = {}
        self.components = []

    def dfs(self, v):
        self.lowlink[v] = self.index[v] = len(self.index)
        self.stack.append(v)
        self.stackset.add(v)
        self.minreach[v] = v
        for w in self.graph[v]:
            if w not in self.index:
                self.dfs(w)
                self.lowlink[v] = min(self.lowlink[v], self.lowlink[w])
            elif w in self.stackset:
                self.lowlink[v] = min(self.lowlink[v], self.index[w])
            self.minreach[v] = min(self.minreach[v], self.minreach[w])
        if self.lowlink[v] == self.index[v]:
            component = set()
            while True:
                w = self.stack.pop()
                self.stackset.remove(w)
                self.minreach[w] = self.minreach[v]
                component.add(w)
                if w == v:
                    break
            self.components.append(component)

    def scc(self):
        for v in self.graph:
            if v not in self.index:
                self.dfs(v)
        return self.components, self.minreach


if __name__ == "__main__":
    g = random_graph(6)
    print(g)
    components, minreach = SCC(g).scc()
    print(components)
    print(minreach)
```